# How to use arguments in cloned object?

Tags: java, arguments, clone

So let say I have such prototyping:

```
private static Hashtable<String, Furniture> map  = 
                        new Hashtable<String, Furniture>();

public My_product() {
    loadCache();
}

public My_Product createProduct(String type, String name) {
    Furniture cachedproduct = map.get(type);
    return  (Furniture) cachedproduct.clone();
}

private static void loadCache() {
    Sub_product1 pr1 = new Sub_product1(null);
    map.put("pr1", pr1);
    Sub_product2 pr2 = new Sub_product2(null);
    map.put("pr2", pr2);
}
```

So when I make an instance of an object, I don't know what value will be entered after cloning it (creating object using cloning). So I chosen null value for object instance. But when I clone it then I know what value needs to be assigned for that object. So how could I specify while cloning to put some value instead of `null` one from object instance?

As you can see in method `createProduct` method, there is argument called `name`. I would like that name to be used in cloned object, but how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use setter methods?

```
public My_Product createProduct(String type, String name) {
    Furniture cachedproduct = map.get(type);
    Furniture clonedProduct = (Furniture) cachedproduct.clone();
    clonedProduct.setType(type);
    clonedProduct.setName(name);
    return clonedProduct;
}
```

However, I'm still not clear on the whole idea of this cloning of cached objects from the map. Is your product instantiation very expensive? What's the trick?

Comment: Thanks. It works. Well I read that cloning is not good, but I needed to test how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass arguments through the Java built-in clone mechanism. You could provide a setter on the `Furniture` class to change the name after it has been cloned.

Note that cloning in Java is generally considered broken. It is a brittle way to create objects. Generally you are better of using the *factory* pattern, e.g. something like:

```
interface FurnitureBuilder {
   Furniture build(String name);
}

class SubProduct1Builder implements FurnitureBuilder {
   public Furniture build(String name) { return new SubProduct1(name); }
}

class MyFurnitureFactory {
    private final Map<String, FurnitureBuilder> builderByType = ... 
    // initialization omitted

    public Furniture create(String type, String name) {
       return builderByType.get(type).build(name); // null check omitted!
    }
}
```